# Evernote app "Tips" image overlaying UITableView

Tags: cocoa-touch, core-animation, image-manipulation

The Evernote application has a tips pane which hangs over a UITableView on the initial window. When you click on tips, a straight forward animation happens with a tips pane sliding up into view.

My question is, how is that tips pane implemented in the sense that, you absolutely have to click on the tab sticking out for it to animate. Any pixel to the left of it will indeed hit the UITableViewCell. Is this a Core Graphics/Quartz trick or is it just a transparent image? It's quite difficult to articulate what I'm trying to ask here, but I hope someone understands.

Here's a screenshot of the tips pane at the bottom of the home screen of the Evernote app: http://dl-client.getdropbox.com/u/57676/evernote.jpg

Answer (score 2):

It's probably using a transparent image and overrides `-hitTest:withEvent:` to declare the transparent parts of the image as not being part of the view.

Another possibility is it's two views, one for the tab and one for the rest of the pane, but that seems like more work to keep everything in sync.